# Page Rank, Page Autority, Domain Autority

Tags: seo, domains, page

wanted to know how long does it take for Google to update the pagerank of a site and verify the relationships created in web (backlinks).

Another thing, create a relationship with a page that has the authority page very low and Domain Authority very good. That kind of relationship would add to the positioning of my site?

Greetings,

Comment: I highly recommend that you abandon the SEO advice you are currently reading with something more current. Google has not updated visible PageRank since March 2014. If you mean actual page rankings and not PageRank then Google updates this daily and varies from site to site, from niche to niche. How valuable a link is to the relationship to your site is impossible for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, PageRank hasn't been updated since Dec. 2013, so for all intents and purposes it would be considered a 'dead' metric.

That's not to say that Google don't have a Pagerank 2.0 used to measure has authority, relevance and trust flow within an IA.

Also, please keep in mind that Page Authority and Domain Authority, as well as others metrics, are *private, proprietary metrics* and are merely *observations* on aggregated data: they are not official and simply a guide.

For these proprietary metrics, they are updated depending on the volume and volatility of the search times used. If your url ranks well for seasonal terms for example, the insights they provide are wrong or misleading. If you are a new website, it can also be completely mispleading.

Anyway, to answer your questions:

- **Pagerank** Never again (as of Dec. 6th, 2013)
- **Page Authority and Domain Authority:** [Mozscape Index is updated approximately once per month](https://moz.com/help/guides/research-tools/open-site-explorer/updates).

Comment: PageRank is not being made public, however, it is still maintained with less emphasis on this metric than in the past. It is still a very real metric. This is a slight variation on what you said in your answer but closer to the announcement. PageRank was/is, at the time of the announcement, a batch oriented calculation that would update a set of table(s) that were made public via the tool bar and API. They just simply stopped updating the table in an effort to prevent gaming the system. I also believe that the PageRank batch process does not run as frequently as 4 times a year anymore.